# How to create a file with file_name as the output of present command?

Tags: shell, touch, md5, xargs

**Problem**

I have a file which is present in `/home/user/Samples/` folder now i have a seperate folder `/home/user/Reports/`. Suppose i have a sample `DOG.zip` file in Samples folder, Now i want to generate a report of this sample and store it in Reports folder and name it as `MD5` of the file

**What i did**

```
cd /home/user/Samples/
md5sum DOG.zip | xargs touch ../Reports/{}
```

But this is producing `{}` file in Reports folder but not a empty file with the md5 as file name.

Any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. I think you do not want `touch /home/user/Reports/md5`.  
Something like `file=DOG.zip; md5sum "${file}"; touch "../Reports/${file}"`,  or do this for all results, or redirect output of md5 to a file in reports, or change name from `DOG.zip` into `DOG.md5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `-i` to xargs to "enable" the `{}` placeholder:

```
$ seq 10 | xargs echo foo{}
foo{} 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$ seq 10 | xargs -i echo foo{}
foo1
foo2
foo3
foo4
foo5
foo6
foo7
foo8
foo9
foo10
```